# Passar um Select sql para o padrão usado no Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

Em meu phpMyAdmin, uso o SQL abaixo:

```
select categorias.id as categoria_id, 
nome as categoria_nome, 
count(*) as Quantidade from `livros` 
inner join `categorias` on `livros`.`categoria_id` = `categorias`.`id` group by `categoria_id`
```

O SQL acima funciona dando o resultado abaixo:

```
categoria_id  categoria_nome      Quantidade
2             MEDICINA LEGAL      1
3             HISTÓRIA DO BRASIL  4
4             HISTÓRIA DO DIREITO 5
5             BIOGRAFIA           2
```

porém quando tento passar ele para o Laravel 6 usando a sintaxe abaixo:

```
$dados = DB::table('livros')
            ->join('categorias', 'livros.categoria_id', '=', 'categorias.id')
            ->select(
                DB::raw('categorias.id as category_id'),
                DB::raw('nome as category_name'),
                DB::raw('count(*) as Quantidade'))
            ->groupBy('categoria_id')
            ->get();
```

dá o erro abaixo:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'books.categorias.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select categorias.id as categoria_id, nome as categoria_name, count(*) as Quantidade from `livros` inner join `categorias` on `livros`.`categoria_id` = `categorias`.`id` group by `categoria_id`)
```

Onde posso estar errando nisso?

Comment: No lugar de categoria_id coloque categoria.id.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic colocar no groupBy ? Se sim, coloquei e deu isso: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'categoria.id' in 'group statement' (SQL: select categorias.id as category_id, nome as category_name, count(*) as Quantidade from `livros` inner join `categorias` on `livros`.`categoria_id` = `categorias`.`id` group by `categoria`.`id`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido acrescentando as linhas abaixo no **config\database.php** do Laravel 6:

```
'mysql' => [

       'strict' => true,// acrescentado as linhas abaixo
       'modes' => [

            'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES',
            'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE',
            'NO_ZERO_DATE',
            'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO',
            'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER',
            'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
        ],
 ]
```